# How to get Client coordinate rather then Screen coordinate using MSDN\C++

Tags: c++, client, screen, msdn, coordinate

[image: help plz]

So, I'm trying to get the client coordinates for my mouseX/mouseY variable on the application window.
I am able to get the "screen coordinates", but now I need the "client coordinates".

Part of the code is in the picture. 
I'm not sure what method to call to get access to the "client coordinates"

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ScreenToClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.x;
pt.y = pointerInfo.ptPixelLocation.y;
if (ScreenToClient(hTheWindowYouCareAbout, &pt)) {
    // Do something here...
}
```